# Drupal 7 - login/registration on the same page - error in registration form after login attempt

Tags: forms, drupal

I created page with login and registration forms on the same page using panels (two columns layout and blocks). In template file for login block I have:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
```

In register block I have:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
```

But I have problem with submitting forms with incorrect data. After submitting register form I have errors only in register form (correct), but after submitting login form I have errors in login form and register form.

Do You know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan module will do this for you: Install it, and go to admin/config/system/logintoboggan; select "Present a unified login/registration page."

also if you want write your own module, you can look at its source

Comment: Great module, but in my case the problem remains. I've checked this module with just installed drupal instance and there everything is ok. So problem is somewhere in my modifications. Thx for help